# $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ doesn't have principal maximal ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Prove that $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ doesn't have principal maximal ideals.

Please, I need help with this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Given any principal ideal, you can easily find a larger ideal. Take the two cases of principal ideals which are generated by constants and by non-constants.

Comment: The maximal ideals of $\mathbb{Z[x]}$ are of the form $(p, f(x))$ where $f(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial modulo $p$. Now assume that this ideal is generated by a signle polynomial and you would derive a contradiction.

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1591558/nonconstant-polynomials-do-not-generate-maximal-ideals-in-mathbb-zx/1591594#1591594

Answer (score 6):

Here is a detailed outline:

Let $I$ be a principal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Now there is some $f(x)\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ such that $\langle f(x)\rangle=I$.

If $\deg(f(x))=0$, then $f(x)$ is a constant $c$. If $c=0$ or $c=1$, then $I$ cannot be maximal. (why?) Now assume $c\neq 0,1$ and show that $\langle c\rangle \subsetneq \langle c, x \rangle \subsetneq \mathbb{Z}[x]$. Thus $I$ is not maximal.

If $\deg(f(x))>0$, then $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+\cdots + a_nx^n$ for some $n>0$. Now show that $\langle f(x)\rangle \subsetneq \langle f(x), q \rangle \subsetneq \mathbb{Z}[x]$, where $q$ is a prime that does not divide $a_n$. Thus $I$ is not maximal.

Comment: Could you  kindly explain why $\langle f(x), q \rangle \subsetneq \mathbb{Z}[x]$ ?

Comment: @SameerKulkarni  Note that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle f(x),q\rangle = \mathbb{Z}_q[x]/\langle f(x) \rangle $ which isn't the trivial ring.

Comment: See also [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1591581/121097). Let me mention that this proof works for $R[X]$, where $R$ is a UFD having infinitely many primes. (+1)