# Prime ideals in $R[x]$, $R$ a PID

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> Let $R$ be a PID. Show that if $\mathfrak p \subset R[x]$ is a prime ideal, $(r) = \left\{h(0) \colon h(x) \in \mathfrak p \right\}$, and $$\mathfrak p = (r, f(x), g(x)),$$ where $f(x), g(x) \in R[x]$ are nonconstant irreducible polynomials, then $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are associates. So $\mathfrak p = (r, f(x))$.

Comment: $\mathfrak p=(2,X,X+2)$ is prime in $\mathbb Z[X]$ (in fact, $\mathfrak p=(2,X)$), but $X$ and $X+2$ are not associate.

Comment: Btw, the conclusion follows if $r=0$. Otherwise, I don't think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated, the claim being made in the post is false, as user26857 makes clear in the comments. To reiterate, a counterexample is $$\mathfrak{p} = (2, x, x+2) \subset \mathbf{Z}[x].$$

Answer (score 3):

After seeing the comments below I see that

1)[most importantly] my answer was clearly wrong
2) the OP question cannot be solved as the counterexample of user26857 shows: $(2,x,x+2)=(x,2)=\{h(x) \in \mathbb Z[x] \mid h(0)=2\}$, so $r=2$ and $x$ and $x+2$ are not associated.

Since the OP aims seems to be following

> I am trying to solve an exercise to show that every prime ideal in R[x] is of the form (r,f(x))

as amend I'll give a sketch of a possible solution to the problem.

The idea is to consider for a generic prime $p$ in $R[x]$ the ideal $p'=p \cap R$ which is prime in $R$. Since $R$ is a PID we have two possibilities

- $p'=(0)$: in this case one can consider an irreducible polynomial $f$ of minimal degree in $p$ (this polynomial exists as a consequence of the primality of $p$). The one can consider a generic $g \in p \setminus \{0\}$ and the ideal $(f,g)$ in $K(R)[x]$ proving that $(f,g)=(f)$ in $K(R)[x]$ and then using Gauss Lemma to conclude that $p=(f)$.
- $p'=(r)$ for some $r \ne 0$: in this case $R[x]/p \cong (R[x]/(r))/(p/(r))$. Up to the isomorphism $R[x]/(r) \cong R/(r)[x]$ we have that $R/(r)$ is a field (because $(r)$ is a not null prima ideal of a PID, hence it is maximal) so $p/(r)$ is principal ($R/(r)[x]$ is a PID, indeed an Euclid ring) and so it is generated by *the image of a polynomial $f \in R[x]$* under the homomorphism $R[x] \to R/(r)[x]$.
  Since $p/(r)=(\bar f)$ by the theorem on ideals of quotient rings $p=(r,f)$, of course the case $f=0$ is contemplated.

The hardest part to work out is the first one ($p'=(0)$) because the details are a little boring but it is an easy exercise, feel free to ask if something does not add up.

Comment: Very clear, thanks.

Comment: Upon going over this again, I think there might be a problem with your answer. You say that $d(x)$ must be associated with $\underline{f(x)}$ and $\underline{g(x)}$, but $d(x)$ could be a constant; for example, if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are *not* associates, then $d(x) = 1$. Notice that your solution doesn't use the hypothesis that the ideal $p$ is prime.

Comment: I have to edit the question to add that $r$ is defined as the generator of $\left\{f(0) \colon f(x) \in p \right\}$.

Comment: Notice as well that the answer, as written, appears to imply that any two nonconstant, irreducible polynomials are associates, which is not true.

Comment: Well, I had originally accepted it, but then I went through it again and saw this potential error, and so I was waiting to have my observation validated before unaccepting the answer.

Comment: @pseudoname123456 The bad news is that (not only this answer, but) the question is wrong as well.

Comment: Yea. I am trying to solve an exercise to show that every prime ideal in $R[x]$ is of the form $(r, f(x))$ and I came up with this (false) claim that I asked above. I know a prime $\mathfrak{p}$ is of the form $(r, f_1(x), ..., f_n(x))$ since $R[x]$ is Noetherian, and I was trying to go from there.

Comment: Note that we may use the primality of $\mathfrak{p}$ to say that the $f_i(x)$ are nonconstant irreducible.  I want to proceed by induction, showing $f_n(x) \in (r, f_1(x), ..., f_{n-1}(x))$ (trying to generalize your example above).  Say $\mathfrak{p} = (r, f(x), g(x))$.  I want to show $g(x) \in (r, f(x))$. If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are not associates, then, passing to the field of fractions, there are $a(x)$, $b(x)$ in $R[x]$ and $s \in R$ such that $a(x)f(x) + b(x)g(x) = rs$.  I cannot figure out how to proceed from here.

Comment: Also, I think I defined $r$ incorrectly. I think it is supposed to be the generator of the set of constants in $\mathfrak{p}$, contrary to what I wrote above.

Comment: Unfortunately I've been for a long time far away from an internet connection. I see the problems with the answer, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: I've made some changes to the answer, with some additional data that I hope may help you to solve the problem you were addressing.

Comment: Actually the proof for $R=\mathbb Z$ works as well for $R$ a PID. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174595/classification-of-prime-ideals-of-mathbbzx

Comment: @user26857 indeed my proof is based on an adaptation of the proof for $\mathbb Z$ :)