# Finding maximal in $\Bbb Z[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory

**Problem**
Let $f(x)$ be a non-constant element in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ . Prove that $\langle f(x) \rangle$ is not maximal in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$

**Attempt**
$\langle f(x) \rangle \subset \langle 1 \rangle \subset \mathbb{Z}$ . Is this wrong?

Comment: I edited your post just to clean up the $\LaTeX$ a little.  Remember your "\$" signs!  Cheers!

Comment: So, can you name a non-constant element of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ that could be the $f(x)$ in your attempt?  In particular, can you exhibit a non-constant $f(x)$ satisfying $f(x) \in \langle 1 \rangle$?

Comment: @RobertLewis Thanks a lot.

Comment: @blueboy:  my pleasure, sir.  By the way, did you take your handle from the famous painting?

Comment: all the prime ideals and maximal ideals of Z[x] are sure https://math.stackexchange.com/q/174595/453628

Comment: @RobertLewis sorry i don't know, it was set at random. Anyways my knowledge in this field (Art) is abysmal. Only painters i have heard of are Picasso and Van Gogh. It is sad. :)

Answer (score 4):

Consider the leading coefficient of $f$.  If $(f(x))$ is maximal, then $\Bbb{Z}[x]/(f(x))$ is a field $K$.  Since no constant element is in $(f(x))$, $K$ has characteristic $0$, i.e., $p\ne 0$ in $K$ for all primes $p=1+\cdots +1$ ($p$ times).  In $K$ each such $p$ must be invertible.  Consider $2$.  Multiplying by $2^{-1}$ in $K$ shows that to any element $g+(f)$ in $K$ there corresponds an $h+(f) = 2^{-1}g+(f)$, i.e., for any $g$ there is an $h$ such that $f$ divides $2h-g$.  In particular, there is an $h$ such that $f$ divides $2h-1$.  Since $f$ is not constant, this means its leading coefficient is divisible by $2$.  (Do the long division, and you'll see this.)  Repeating this argument for every prime, the leading coefficient of $f$ is divisible by every prime, a contradiction.