# Any maximal ideal intersect its proper subring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let M  is maximal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$  then is it true that M intersect with $\mathbb{Z}$ non trivially?

Any hint is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174595/classification-of-prime-ideals-of-mathbbzx?noredirect=1&lq=1).  Also see your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3266770/the-maximal-ideals-of-mathbbzx-is-of-the-form-p-fx).

Answer (score 3):

By the [classification of maximal ideals of $\mathbb Z[x]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/174595/29335) the maximal ideals all contain a prime $p$ of $\mathbb Z$.  So yes.

Comment: No,,  you cannot use that because I want to prove classification of maximal ideal that is why  I need this.  So any other process plz

Comment: @Siraj Having withheld vital context from your question, you are in no position to object to the method.

Answer (score 0):

It is shown in [this reference](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/voloch/Homework/zx.pdf) that maximal ideals in $Z[x]$ are all of the form $\langle p, f(x) \rangle$, where $p \in \Bbb Z$ is a prime and $f(x) \in Z[x]$ is irreducible $\mod p$.  Thus a maximal ideal $M \subset Z[x]$ contains a prime and hence $M \cap \Bbb Z \ne \emptyset$.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to use this result to prove the classification of maximal ideals. To this end, note that if $M$ is a maximal ideal of $\mathbb Z[x]$, then $F:=\mathbb Z[x]/M$ is a field, and is finitely generated as a $\mathbb Z$-algebra. This cannot happen for $\mathbb Q$, so the field has positive characteristic, and hence $M$ contains some prime $p\in\mathbb Z$.