# How to determine if an ideal is prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Specifically, I'm working on the following problem:

> Let $I$ be an ideal in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ generated by $5$ and $x^3+x+1$. Is $I$ a prime ideal? Prove or disprove.

I believe $I$ is prime, but I don't have any strong intuition as to why. It seems like it should be because $5$ is prime and $x^3+x+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}$, but I don't know of any results that guarantee this. So I could try to do a direct proof using the definition of prime ideal: Suppose $ab\in I$ and show that $a\in I$ or $b\in I$, or the contrapositive; suppose $a,b\notin I$ and show that $ab\notin I$ (or even use these to show $I$ is not prime). But I'm not sure how to use either of these directions because $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is the ring of polynomials with integer coefficients and powers of $x^3+x+1$ can give terms of any desired degree.

Thus, my inclination is to try to use the first isomorphism theorem and the fact that $I$ is prime if and only if $\mathbb{Z}[x]/I$ is an integral domain. $I$ is certainly the kernel of some homomorphism. So if I can explicitly define some map $\Phi:\mathbb{Z}[x]\rightarrow S\subseteq R$ such that $R$ is an integral domain and $\ker(\Phi)=I$, then the desired result will follow.

Specifically, my questions are as follows:

1. Is there a "quick" way to look at an ideal like this and decide if it's prime or not?
2. Is a direct proof using the definition of prime ideal feasible here and if so, how?
3. Regardless of if a direct proof is feasible, how can I complete the argument using the first isomorphism theorem (assuming $I$ is in fact prime)?

Comment: How about considering $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}[x] =R$ then quotient by $R/(x^3+x+1)$

Comment: A very concise hint: is the polynomial $X^3+X+\overline{1}$ irreducible over the field $\mathbb{Z}_5=\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @ΑΘΩ Yes, because if it were reducible, it would have a linear factor, and it's easily verified that it does not. So this implies that $\mathbb{Z}_5/(x^3+x+1)$ is an integral domain. Thus $(x^3+x+1)$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}_5$. But I'm not sure how this gets me to the desired result.

Comment: Ring modulo ideal is integral domain if and only if ideal is prime. So you want to show $\mathbb Z[x]$ mod $I$ is an integral domain, but that's the same as showing for $\mathbb Z_5[x]$ modulo $(x^3+x+1)$ instead. Alternatively for your initial approach you can see there are only finitely many residue classes for $a,b$ so an inefficient but direct way is to test all $a,b\neq 0$ mod $I$ and see if any gives $ab=0$ mod $I$. The "quick" way for $\mathbb Z[x]$ is probably via proving the [classification.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174595/classification-of-prime-ideals-of-mathbbzx)

Comment: @YongHaoNg Why is it that $\mathbb{Z}_5/(x^3+x+1)$ being an integral domain implies that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/I$ is an integral domain?

Comment: @Atsina $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]/(x^3+x+1)$ and $\mathbb{Z}[x]/I$ are isomorphic as rings. You can construct the surjective map $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^3+x+1) \to \mathbb{Z}_5[x]/(x^3+x+1)$ and apply the 1st isomorphism theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is clearest if we construct the isomorphism in stages. There is the natural surjective map
$$
\mathbb{Z}[x] \to \mathbb{Z}_5[x]
$$
with kernel $(5)$, thus giving 
$$
\mathbb{Z}[x]/(5) \cong \mathbb{Z}_5[x]
$$
by the 1st isomorphism theorem. Similarly, there is the surjective map
$$
\mathbb{Z}_5[x] \to \mathbb{Z}_5[x]/(x^3+x+1)
$$
with kernel $(x^3+x+1)$. Using our first isomorphism, we can write
$$
\mathbb{Z}_5[x]/(x^3+x+1) \cong (\mathbb{Z}[x]/(5))/(x^3+x+1) \cong \mathbb{Z}[x]/(5, x^3+x+1) = \mathbb{Z}[x]/I
$$
where we have subtly used the third isomorphism theorem. As noted in the comments, $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]/(x^3+x+1)$ is an integral domain (and a field), thus so is $\mathbb{Z}[x]/I$. Hence $I$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Comment: Can you do a step by step reasoning of why $(Z[x]/(5))/(x^3 + x+1) \cong Z[x]/(5, x^3 + x + 1)$? I cannot seem to work it out using the third isomorphism theorem.

Comment: @minimino: Even though some might say we are being pedantic about elementary matters, these matters are still very important which is why in the answer below I tried to describe in more detail what machinery is used in order to obtain the isomorphism you ask of.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are users of this forum who would like to see a more explicit presentation, may I introduce a very general treatment.

In a given arbitrary ring, instead of using the terminology ''two-sided ideals'' I will instead call these **bilateral ideals**; given subset $X \subseteq A$ of ring $A$ I will write $(X)_{\mathrm{b}}$ for the bilateral ideal generated by $X$. Given two sets $M \subseteq N$ we use the notation

$$\mathrm{i}_{N}^{M}: M \to N\\
\mathrm{i}_{N}^M(x)=x$$

to refer to **the inclusion map** between the two respective sets.

For $I \subseteq A$ a bilateral ideal of ring $A$, we will denote **the canonical surjection onto the quotient** through $I$ by

$$\sigma_I^A: A \to A/I$$

In the one indeterminate polynomial ring $A[X]$, for any polynomial $f$ let us agree to **denote its coefficient of degree $n$ by** $f_n$. With this convention in place for arbitrary subset $M \subseteq A$ let us define
$$M[X]=\{f \in A[X]|\ (\forall n)(n \in \mathbb{N} \Rightarrow f_n \in M)\}$$

the **set of all polynomials whose coefficients lie in the subset** $M$.

Given rings $A, B$ and morphism $\varphi: A \to B$, by **the universality property of polynomial rings** there will exist a unique morphism $\psi: A[X] \to B[X]$ such that the relations

$$\psi \circ \mathrm{i}_{A[X]}^A=\mathrm{i}_{B[X]}^B \circ \varphi\\
\psi(X)=X$$

are both satisfied; we call this unique morphism **the extension of $\varphi$ to the respective one indeterminate polynomial rings** and denote it by $\psi=\varphi[X]$.

The following results are immediate from the definitons:

> **Proposition 1.** Let $A$ be an arbitrary ring and $I \subseteq A$ a bilateral ideal. Then in the one indeterminate polynomial ring we have $(I)_{\mathrm{b}}=I[X]$.

---

> **Proposition 2.** Let $A, B$ be arbitrary rings and $\varphi: A \to B$. The extension of $\varphi$ to the one indeterminate polynomial rings has the properties:

- a) $\mathrm{Ker}(\varphi[X])=(\mathrm{Ker}\varphi)[X]$
- b) $\mathrm{Im}\varphi[X]=(\mathrm{Im}\varphi)[X]$

Let us remark that as a consequence of this proposition we gather that surjective morphisms have surjective extensions to the respective polynomial rings.

Let us also recall the following version of the

> **Theorem of induced quotient maps:** Let $A, B$ be two arbitrary rings, $f: A \to B$ a ring morphism and $I \subseteq A, J \subseteq B$ two bilateral ideals such that $f(I) \subseteq J$. Then there will exist a unique ring morphism $g: A/I \to B/J$ satisfying 
>   $$g \circ \sigma_I^A=\sigma_J^B \circ f$$ 
>   This unique morphism $g$ will be called **the morphism induced by** $f$ and has the following properties:

1. $\mathrm{Ker}g=f^{-1}(J)/I$ so in particular $g$ is **injective if and only if** $f^{-1}(J)=I$
2. $\mathrm{Im}g=(\mathrm{Im}f+J)/J$ so in particular $g$ is **surjective if and only if** $B=f(A)+J$.

Let us remark that we have the following immediate

> **Corollary:** if in the above $f$ is surjective such that $f^{-1}(J)=I$ then the induced map $g$ is an isomorphism.

Having introduced this theoretical apparatus, let us apply it to the concrete problem posted above: consider first the canonical surjection $\sigma: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_5$ , such that $\mathrm{Ker}\sigma=5\mathbb{Z}$, surjection which by the consequence of proposition 2 will have a surjective extension $\varphi:=\sigma[X]$ to the respective polynomial rings. Note that by claim a) of proposition 2 we can infer that
$$\mathrm{Ker}\varphi=(5\mathbb{Z})[X]=5\mathbb{Z}[X]$$

Agreeing to simplify notation by $\sigma(n)=\overline{n}$ for any integer $n$, we have that $\psi(X^3+X+1)=X^3+X+\overline{1}$, by which $\varphi((X^3+X+1)\mathbb{Z}[X])=(X^3+X+\overline{1})\mathbb{Z}_5 [X]$ and hence 
$$\varphi^{-1}((X^3+X+\overline{1})\mathbb{Z}_5 [X])=(X^3+X+1)\mathbb{Z}[X]+\mathrm{Ker}\varphi=(X^3+X+1)+(5)=(X^3+X+1, 5)$$

where **we have used another relation ubiquitous in algebra**, namely 
$$f^{-1}(f(X))=X \mathrm{Ker}f=\mathrm{Ker}f X$$
valid for any group morphism $f: G \to G'$ between (multiplicatively written) groups $G, G'$ and any subset $X \subseteq G$.

At this stage, we can apply the corollary to the theorem of induced quotient maps to the particular case $A=\mathbb{Z}[X], B=\mathbb{Z}_5 [X]$, surjective morphism $\varphi: A \to B$ and ideals 
$$J=(X^3+X+\overline{1}),\ I=\varphi^{-1}(J)=(X^3+X+1, 5)$$
in order to infer the existence of an isomorphism

$$\psi: \mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^3+X+1, 5) \to \mathbb{Z}_5 [X]/(X^3+X+\overline{1})$$

If for arbitrary $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ we agree to write $\mathbb{Z}_n=\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ and for any polynomial $f \in\mathbb{Z}[X]$ to denote its canonical image in $\mathbb{Z}_n [X]$ by $\overline{f}$ (image which is obtained by extending the canonical surjection $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_n$ to the corresponding polynomial rings and applying this extension to $f$; this is typically referred to as **reducing $f$ modulo** $n$), the above reasoning serves to prove that more generally one has

$$\mathbb{Z}[X]/(f, n) \approx \mathbb{Z}_n [X]/(\overline{f})\ (\mathbf{Ann})$$

where by $\mathbf{Ann}$ we refer to the category of rings, in the sense that the above isomorphism occurs precisely in that category (simply put, the two quotients above are canonically isomorphic as rings).