# when can we assume without loss of generality that p(x) is monic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation

I'm reading the proof here: [Classification of prime ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174595/classification-of-prime-ideals-of-mathbbzx)

The part I am having trouble with is the following.

We are considering the case where $P$ is an ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, and $P \cap \mathbb{Z} = (p)$ for some prime $p$. Then we consider the image of $P$ by the isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(p) \cong F_p[x]$. we are concerned with the case where $p(x)$ is a polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ that reduces to irreducible polynomial in $F_p[x]$.

[image]

What I do not get is that we assume $p(x)$ is monic, but I have no idea how to justify that assumption.

If someone could clear up my misunderstanding, I would be grateful.

Thanks.

Comment: $p(x)$ can be any polynomial reducing to $q(x) \bmod p$, and you can choose such a polynomial to be monic, since $q(x)$ is monic. (And $q(x)$ is monic WLOG because $\mathbb{F}_p$ is a field.)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan say $3x+1$, that reduces to x+1 in $F_2$. What would "make" $3x+1$ monic?

Comment: Nothing is "making" $3x + 1$ monic. It's just that in the argument $p(x)$ can be *any* polynomial reducing to $q(x) \bmod p$, as in we are free to *choose* it, and the answerer chooses it so that it's monic. In your example we can choose $p(x) = x + 1$ instead.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan  ah yeah, I missed the quantify. That makes sense, thanks!