# Irreducible polynomial with integer coefficients of degree $> 1$ has no rational roots

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

In the middle of a homework problem I realized I proved this lemma: an irreducible polynomial $q \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ with $\deg q > 1$ has no rational roots. This seems... odd, since many well-known theorems on irreducibility and existence of roots for polynomials with integer coefficients (like the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) and [Eisenstein's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion)) do not go this far. What went wrong in this proof? Or otherwise, am I missing a super easy corollary of the definition of an irreducible polynomial that makes the lemma trivial? Any hints are appreciated.

Here is the proof:

Assume $\beta$ is a root of $q$. Since $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is a PID we have that $I = (q)$ is a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and so $K = \mathbb{Z}[x]/I$ is a field. Define $f: K \to \mathbb{Q}$ by $f(r + I) = r(\beta)$; this map is well defined because if $r + I = s + I$ then $r - s \in I = (p)$, so $r(x) - s(x) = t(x) p(x)$ for some $t \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ and thus $r(\beta) = s(\beta) + t(\beta) p(\beta) = s(\beta)$. This map is also a field homomorphism since $(r + s)(\beta) = r(\beta) + s(\beta)$ and $(rs)(\beta) = r(\beta) s(\beta)$. Being a homomorphism between fields, $f$ is injective. If $r(\beta) = 0$ then $r + I \in \ker f = \{I\}$ and so $r \in I = (q)$; this means, in particular, that $\deg r \geq \deg q > 1$ (I'm adopting the convention that $\deg 0 = \infty$), so any polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ with $\beta$ as a root has degree greater than $1$. But if $\beta = a/b \in \mathbb{Q}$ then the polynomial $r(x) = bx - a \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ has $r(\beta) = 0$ and $\deg r = 1$, a contradiction. Hence $\beta \notin \mathbb{Q}$ and so $q$ has no rational roots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> “Since $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is a PID...”

Ehr... no, it isn’t. $(2,x)$ is not principal.

It’s also not true that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(q)$ is a field when $q$ is irreducible: $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x)\cong\mathbb{Z}$ is not a field (this because $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is not a PID, so $(q)$ need not be maximal). I don’t think your proof can be salvaged at this point.

Note that [maximal ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174595/classification-of-prime-ideals-of-mathbbzx)
have the form $(q(x),p)$, where $q$ is an irreducible polynomial of degree greater than or equal to $1$, and $p$ is a rational prime. The quotient will be a field of positive characteristic.

---

Your result *is* true: it follows from Gauss’s Lemma: Gauss’s Lemma says that if $p(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is such that the gcd of its coefficients is $1$, and $p(x) = r(x)s(x)$ with $r(x),s(x)\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$, then there exist polynomials $R(x),S(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$, $\deg(R)=\deg(r)$, $\deg(S)=\deg(s)$, such that $p(x) = R(x)S(x)$.

In particular, if a polynomial $p(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, then it remains irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. In particular, it cannot have rational roots if $\deg(p)\gt 1$.

Also, note that

1. The Rational Root Theorem is not about irreducible polynomials; it has nothing to say about it, and it just gives you a finite list of *possible* roots. I don’t think it is related to the result.
2. Eisenstein’s Criterion allows you to deduce irreducibility in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$: as such, it necessarily implies no roots when the polynomial has degree greater than $1$. So I do not understand why you say its conclusion “does not go as far” as the result at hand. Having no roots in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is *weaker* than being irreducible.

Comment: I see, thank you! I can't believe I didn't check the first fact I used.

Comment: @lizardknight: Also, you would have had to check that your homomorphism is not the *zero* homomorphism. Not every ring homomorphism between fields is $1$ to $1$...