# Examine whether $(X^2+4,X)$ is maximal ideal of $\Bbb Z[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

We want to examine whether the ideal $I=(X^2+4,X)$ is a maximal ideal of $\Bbb Z[X]$, which as we know is not a PID.

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/174595/326865) result tells us precisely which are the maximal ideals of $\Bbb Z[X]$. Thus it seems that this is not maximal, but I can't see why if so. It might be easy but I feel I stuck here.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Consider: what could you add to the ideal without it becoming the unit ideal? For example, the link you mentioned references ideals of the form (p, f), where p is a prime number. So, consider the ideal generated by $I$ and $2$, and check if it's the unit ideal.

Comment: Hint: $(X^2+4,X)=(4,X)$

Comment: Use the *third isomorphism theorem*.

Comment: $I$ is a maximal ideal of $A$ if and only if the quotient $A/I$ is a field. Can you compute the quotient ring?

Comment: This was what I couldn't see in fact: $(X^2+4,X)=(4,X)$. Then, 
$$\Bbb Z[X]/(X^2+4,X) = \Bbb Z[X]/(4,X) \cong \Bbb Z_4[X]/(X) \cong \Bbb Z_4$$
and the since the latter is not a field, the first ring is not a field and thus our ideal is not maximal. Thank you all.

Comment: @Desperado Could I ask in general how can we "smell" equalities like this?

Comment: @Chris the idea is to play around with the generators, and ues the fact that any multiple of a generator can be removed by the other generators.

Answer (score 3):

The first way is something more sophisticated. Recall that an ideal $I \subset R$ is a maximal ideal iff $R/I$ is a field. In this case, note that we have $$\frac{\Bbb Z[X]}{(X^2 + 4, X)} \cong \frac{\Bbb Z}{(4)}.$$
The latter is not a field and thus, $(X^2 + 4, X)$ is not maximal.

---

The other way is to explicitly produce a larger proper ideal. To see this, one can note that $$(X^2 + 4, X) \subsetneq (X^2 + 4, X, 2) \subsetneq \Bbb Z[X].$$
(Why are the inclusions proper?)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The first way is a bit nicer indeed and it's in fact a short version of what I wrote in the comments above. As for the second, this was precisely the point I stuck constructing an increasing chain $(X^2 + 4, X) \subsetneq (X^2 + 4, X, 2) \subsetneq (1)$!

Comment: @Chris: Glad to have helped. If you're comfortable with the first way, then that is good because that is, in a way, more "methodical". Indeed, the point is that you just have to compute a quotient and then check if it's a field. In the second way, it seems that one must "cook up" a bigger ideal from nowhere. However, if you wish to explicitly give an example, the first way does helps you with it. Indeed, if $R/I$ is not a field, then it has a non-zero proper ideal. By the ideal correspondence, it is of the form $J/I$ for some ideal $I \subsetneq J \subsetneq R$. This again shows $I$ isn't max.