# There are infinitely many prime ideals contained in $(x,6)\subseteq \mathbb Z[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

My idea is that using [Classification of prime ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174595/classification-of-prime-ideals-of-mathbbzx)

I considered $(x,p)$ where $p>6$ is prime in $\mathbb Z$

or type of $(x^n)$ or $(p)$, but above is not contained in the given ideal and these last two are not prime or again not contained in $(6,x)$

Maybe some hint, answer would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hint: if $p(x)$ is a polynomial whose constant coefficient is divisible by $6$, then $p(x)\in (x,6)$. If $p(x)$ is irreducible, then $(p(x))$ is prime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find an irreducible polynomial $f(x)$ of the form $6a(x) + xb(x)$. Then $(f(x))$ is a prime ideal contained in $(6,x)$. There are many such irreducibles of each degree.